# Cannot get custom notification icon to work with FCM and Android

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

Here is my res folder

```
.
├── drawable
│   └── launch_background.xml
├── drawable-hdpi
│   └── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
├── drawable-mdpi
│   └── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
├── drawable-xhdpi
│   └── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
├── drawable-xxhdpi
│   └── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
├── drawable-xxxhdpi
│   └── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
├── mipmap-hdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-mdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xxhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xxxhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
└── values
    └── styles.xml
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml line

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
  android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

Here is what my notification icon looks like on 5.1.1

```
full color launcher icon in a gray circle
```

[image: full color launcher icon in a gray circle]

Here is what it looks like on a newer version of Android

```
a gray outline of the launcher icon, squircle
```

[image: a gray outline of the launcher icon, squircle]

Here is my xxxhdpi notification icon

```
a white on transparent png of a bell
```

[image: a white on transparent png of a bell]

No matter what I try, I cannot get Android to show the silhouette notification icon that I attempt to provide. I am at a loss.